# Nested uiScrollViews with Cross-Directional Scrolling

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface, uiview, uiscrollview

I would like to nest two uiScrollViews, I want to put a uiImageView into one and have it scroll horizontally (Scroller A). This is paged and contains images – I have this working OK already. I need to have another uiScrollView  (Scroller B) that contains the above scroller A and also other content, like logo, text and buttons. I would like scroller B to be able to scroll vertically (scrolls all content including scroller A ). 
Please see image for clarification, red arrows show scroller A, blue is scroller B

[Image showing more details](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xklxh3qc8rgz7y/uiscrollview.png)

I’m not sure how to add these and what order the scrollers need to be added, I have attempted this a couple of times with strange results, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction please.

A similar app would be the apple app store app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a vertical scroll view add a fixed size view (which contains your horizontal scrollview) on it and increase its content size accordingly.each view will have Preloaded horizontal scroll view.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        y=i*110;
    secondScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 320, 100)];
    [secondScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 45)];//to enable scrolling content size is kept more the 320
        secondScroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        [self.firstScroll addSubview:secondScroll];
        [secondScroll release];
        [self.firstScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, self.firstScroll.contentSize.height+110)];
    }
```

first scroll is added on xib second scroll is created by code

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is the bit I'm stuck at, how do i add the scroll view to the existing scroll view, in code or in the story board? does one of these need to act as a 'child' of the other?

Comment: Make a uiview and add a scroll view on it.add this entire view packet on the vertical scroller